# How to post comment on press enter key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making comment system on status. I want to comment on status by pressing enter key.
But response is not coming on the press enter key. here my function-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#inputComment").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var val = $("#inputComment").val();

        alert("send");
    }
});
}
```

input tag is:

```
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputComment"
                        placeholder="Add your comment"
                        upd="<?php echo $updates['data'][0][5];?>"
                        uid="<?php echo $userdata ['data'][0][1];?>"/>
```

Even I'm not getting alert here. How can I get comment data from input tag.

Comment: $("#inputComment").val(); missed the quotes ?

Comment: Thnaks @senK I Corrected but still facing same problem.

Comment: If you are going to send the whole form you could use a hidden submit button like this: `<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made some minor mistakes. You forgot to to end a string and also to end some brackets.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputComment").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var val = $("#inputComment").val();
      alert("send");
    }        
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputComment" placeholder="Add your comment" upd="1" uid="2" />
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreasFurster I am applying this.

Comment: How Can I get these extra attribute value by jquey.

Comment: When you mean the `upd` and `uid` attributes, you can use `$('#inputComment').attr('upd')`.